# vuejs form Calcuations in LAravel Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, forms, vue.js

I have an issue I know might be basic but has been giving me a headache. Any help is highly appreciated

I have a form named timesheets looping through a dates array in laravel. I am trying to add up form fields hour + hour1 + hour2 and I want them added up and displayed in the  total_hours field.
My problem is only the top row gets added(i don't get any errors in the web console)
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2FnO.jpg

//app.js code

```
        el: '#timesheet',
    data: function(){
        return {
                hour: '',
                hour1: '',
                hour2: '',
                hour3: '',
                hour4: '',
                hour5: '',
                total_hours: ''
      };
    },
        computed: {
            TotalTimesheets: function() {
                return (this.hour + this.hour1 + this.hour2 + this.hour3 + this.hour4 + this.hour5)
            }
        }
```

//my _form.blade.php code:

```
@foreach($dates as $date)

<strong>{{$date->date}}</strong>

<input type="text" name="hour[]" value="0"  id="hour" v-model.number="hour" class="form-control">


@if(empty($analysis->act1))

@else
   <input type="text" name="hour1[]" value="0"  id="hour1" v-model.number="hour1" class="form-control>
@endif                 
@if(empty($analysis->act2))

@else
    <input type="text" name="hour2[]" value="0"  id="hour2" v-model.number="hour2" class="form-contro">
@endif        
@if(empty($analysis->act3))

@else
   <input type="text" name="hour3[]" value="0"  id="hour3" v-model.number="hour3" class="form-control">
@endif                  
@if(empty($analysis->act4))

@else
    <input type="text" name="hour4[]" value="0"  id="hour4" v-model.number="hour4" class="form-control">
@endif              
@if(empty($analysis->act5))

@else
<input type="text" name="hour5[]" value="0"  id="hour5" v-model.number="hour5" class="form-control">

@endif
<input type="text" name="total_hours[]" :value="TotalTimesheets"  id="total_hours" class="form-control" max="9" >


@endforeach

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ $buttonText }}</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are repeating the same data in every row, try to organize every row as an individual component or data as a two-dimensional array

Comment: @AndriyKuba, could you please give me a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you only a guide. This is just a "pseudo code" I did not check it.

Firstly, you need to create a component to render only one row of your sheet. Something like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <strong>{{date}}</strong>  
    <div v-for="(hour, index) in hours" :key="index" >       
      <input type="text" v-model.number="hour.value">  
    </div>    
    <input type="text" :value="total">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    name: 'ActiveHoursRow'
    props:['date','hours'],
    computed:{
      total(){
        return this.hours.reduce((a, v) => a + v);
      }
    }    
  }
</script>
```

Secondly, you need to create a component that renders the whole sheet with the help of row-rendering component.

```
<template>
<div v-for="(row, index) in backendData">
  <ActiveHoursRow :date="row.date" :hours="row.hours" />
</div> 
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    name: 'ActiveHoursRow'
    data: function(){ 
      return {
        "backendData":[
          @foreach($dates as $date)
            {
              "date":"{{$date->date}}",
              "hours": [
                @if(empty($analysis->act1))
                @else
                  {"name":"12_07_2019_act1", "value": 0},
                @endif
                @if(empty($analysis->act2))
                @else
                  {"name":"12_07_2019_act2", "value": 0},
                @endif 
              ]
            },
          @endforeach
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

It also always better to draw data as JSON in and then use it. It is more clear to understand and later you can easily to switch to dynamic loading.

See more about components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: really appreciate Mate, let me try it out and will revert!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, but I decided to use Jquery as shown below.

$(document).on("keyup change paste", "td > input.auto-calc", function() {

```
                row = $(this).closest("tr");


                h = parseFloat(row.find("td input.hour").val()) || 0;
                h1 = parseFloat(row.find("td input.hour1").val()) || 0;
                h2 = parseFloat(row.find("td input.hour2").val()) || 0;
                h3 = parseFloat(row.find("td input.hour3").val()) || 0;
                h4 = parseFloat(row.find("td input.hour4").val()) || 0;
                h5 = parseFloat(row.find("td input.hour5").val()) || 0;


                row.find(".total_hours").val(h + h1 + h2 + h3 + h4 + h5);



                var sum = 0;
                var sum1 = 0;
                var sum2 = 0;
                var sum3 = 0;
                var sum4 = 0;
                var sum5 = 0;
                var sum6 = 0;


                $("input.total_hours").each(function() {

                sum += +$(this).val();
                });
                $("input.hour").each(function() {

                sum1 += +$(this).val();
                });
                $("input.hour1").each(function() {

                sum2 += +$(this).val();
                });
                $("input.hour2").each(function() {

                sum3 += +$(this).val();
                });
                $("input.hour3").each(function() {

                sum4 += +$(this).val();
                });
                $("input.hour4").each(function() {

                sum5 += +$(this).val();
                });
                $("input.hour5").each(function() {

                sum5 += +$(this).val();
                });

                $("#total-month").text(sum);
                $("#total-hour").text(sum1);
                $("#total-hour1").text(sum2);
                $("#total-hour2").text(sum3);
                $("#total-hour3").text(sum4);
                $("#total-hour4").text(sum5);
                $("#total-hour5").text(sum6);

                });

                var i = 0;

                $('.addy').on('click', function () {
                    ++i;
                    addy();
                });
                function addy(){
                    var tr='<tr>'
                            +'<td><input type="text" name="timesheets['+i+'][date]"  id="date[]" class="form-control " data-provide="datepicker"   autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" id="analysis_id" name="timesheets['+i+'][analysis_id]" value="{{$analysis->analysisid}}">'
                            +'<input type="hidden" id="activity_id5" name="timesheets['+i+'][activity_id5]" value="{{@$tact6->activity_id5}}"><input type="hidden" id="activity_id4" name="timesheets['+i+'][activity_id4]" value="{{@$tact5->activity_id4}}"><input type="hidden" id="activity_id3" name="timesheets['+i+'][activity_id3]" value="{{@$tact4->activity_id3}}"><input type="hidden" id="activity_id2" name="timesheets['+i+'][activity_id2]" value="{{@$tact3->activity_id2}}"><input type="hidden" id="activity_id1" name="timesheets['+i+'][activity_id1]" value="{{@$tact2->activity_id1}}"><input type="hidden" id="activity_id" name="timesheets['+i+'][activity_id]" value="{{@$tact1->activity_id}}"></td>'
                            +'<td><input type="text" name="timesheets['+i+'][hour]" value="0"  id="hour"  class="form-control hour auto-calc"></div></td>'
                            +'@if(empty($analysis->act1)) @else <td><input type="number" name="timesheets['+i+'][hour1]" value="0"  id="hour1" class="form-control  hour1 auto-calc"   min="0" max="8"></div></td>@endif'
                            +'@if(empty($analysis->act2)) @else <td><input type="number" name="timesheets['+i+'][hour2]" value="0"  id="hour2" class="form-control  hour2 auto-calc"   min="0" max="8"></div></td>@endif'
                            +'@if(empty($analysis->act3)) @else <td><input type="number" name="timesheets['+i+'][hour3]" value="0"  id="hour3" class="form-control  hour3 auto-calc"   min="0" max="8"></div></td>@endif'
                            +'@if(empty($analysis->act4)) @else <td><input type="number" name="timesheets['+i+'][hour4]" value="0"  id="hour4" class="form-control  hour4 auto-calc"   min="0" max="8"></div></td>@endif'
                            +'@if(empty($analysis->act5)) @else <td><input type="number" name="timesheets['+i+'][hour5]" value="0"  id="hour5" class="form-control  hour5 auto-calc"   min="0" max="8"></div></td>@endif'
                            +'<td><div class="input-group mb-3"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i></span></div><input type="text" name="timesheets['+i+'][total_hours]" id="total_hours"  class="form-control total_hours" max="9" ></div><input type="hidden" id="approved" name="timesheets['+i+'][approved]" value="No"> <input type="hidden" id="approved_by" name="timesheets['+i+'][approved_by]" value="{{$approved->supervisor_id}}"></td>'
                            +'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button></td>'
                            +'</tr>'
                            $('tbody').append(tr);
                    };

                    $('body').on('click','.remove', function () {
                        var last=$('tbody tr').length;

                        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

                });
```